# Convert list of Eithers to an Either with a list in it

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell and I am working on some Haskell code that uses [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) for error handling.  The left element of the Either represents an error, while the right element represents a successful result.  The code often uses the Applicative instance of Either, which seems to be designed for this use case.

Given an object of type `[Either e r]`, what is the most elegant way to turn it into an object of type `Either e [r]`?  The point of this is that we might have an array of return values from some functions we called, and if any of those return values is an error, we want to get that error and throw away everything else.  If multiple elements of the array have an error, I would prefer to get the left-most error if possible.

I was able to solve this problem myself in the code below by writing two functions, one of which is recursive, but is there a better way?

```
type Error = [Char]

myFunc :: [Either Error a] -> Either Error [a]
myFunc = myFunc2 []

myFunc2 :: [a] -> [Either Error a] -> Either Error [a]
myFunc2 r ((Left error):rest) = Left error
myFunc2 r ((Right item):rest) = myFunc2 (r ++ [item]) rest
myFunc2 r [] = Right r

main :: IO()
main = do
  -- This prints: Right [1, 2, 3]
  putStrLn (show (myFunc [Right 1, Right 2, Right 3]))

  -- This prints: Left "division by zero"
  putStrLn (show (myFunc [Right 1, Left "division by zero", Right 3]))
```

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, there's a handy site called [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) where you can type in the type-signature of the function you'd like to see and it will give you suggestions of functions with matching/similar signatures. Sadly, `[Either l r] -> Either l [r]` doesn't seem to be yielding any results :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) from `Control.Monad`:

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

as in:

```
\> import Control.Monad (sequence)

\> sequence [Right 1, Right 2, Right 3]
Right [1,2,3]

\> sequence [Right 1, Left "division by zero", Right 3]
Left "division by zero"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I'm just a beginner so I'm not sure whether to accept this answer or the one that recommends `sequenceA` from Data.Traversable.  What are the advantages of `sequence`?

Comment: @DavidGrayson _default_ implementation is the same; [see `sequence = sequenceA` in source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#Traversable). You would use `sequenceA` if you have an applicative which is not a monad.

Comment: @David Grayson they do the same thing; they are different functions for historical reasons https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal#Redundant_functions

Answer (score 9):

Use [sequenceA](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) of [Data.Traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html)

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I'm just a beginner so I'm not sure whether to accept this answer or the one that recommends `sequence` from Control.Monad.  What are the advantages of `sequenceA`?

Comment: `sequence` and `sequenceA` are the same for `Either`. The reason why they both exist is historical: before the Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal `Applicative` was not a superclass of `Monad` and many functionalities were implemented twice like `traverse` and `mapM`.