# Combinig either type variables

Tags: haskell

I have a function in Haskell which return type is `Either error b`,
and there is "`function x = Right b1`" and for the "`function (x:xs) b =`  I want to get something like `Right [list of b's]`. I don't really know how to explain that, I am new to haskell. I have tried: `function (x:xs) = function x <$> function xs` and
`function (x:xs) b = function x b <*> function xs b`, but I get type mismatch errors. The only thing I want is to get not `[Right b1, Right b2, ...]` but, `Right [b1, b2, b3]`.

Comment: There is a function called `sequence` in Control.Monad that does something you may find helpful (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164997/convert-list-of-eithers-to-an-either-with-a-list-in-it)).

Comment: I have edited the question (at first it wasn't really accurate)

Answer (score 3):

You were actually quite close, if your function is `f :: a -> Either b c`, you can implement this with:

```
function :: [a] -> Either b [c]
function [] = Right []
function (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> function xs
```

But there is no need to implement this yourself. This is a special case of [**`traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse) which can do this on any `Traversable` data structure,  so you can work with:

```
function :: [a] -> Either b [c]
function = traverse f
```

If one of the function calls returns a `Left …`, the first one of the items in the list will be returned.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I have 'function:: a -> b -> Either error b'? It is like 'function x b = Right b'. And now when I am trying to use traverse for 'function (x:xs) b' I get an error about the different number of arguments. Sorry for the wrong question at first

Comment: @qwerty: but you should make a clear distinction between a function that maps to an `Either` object, and another function that will do this for a list of items.

Comment: @qwerty: it is also not clear exactly what the `a` and `b` originate from?

Comment: a and b are just types which I created by myself

Comment: as for the first one, I didn't really get